# How to convert a tensor of booleans to ints in PyTorch?

Tags: int, boolean, pytorch, tensor

Suppose, we have a tensor

```
t = torch.tensor([True, False, True, False])
```

How do we convert it to an integer tensor with values `[1, 0, 1, 0]`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution is just a single line of code.

To convert a tensor `t` with values `[True, False, True, False]` to an integer tensor, just do the following.

```
t = torch.tensor([True, False, True, False])
t_integer = t.long()
print(t_integer)
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: t.int() also works.